# Android application out of memory without dealing with images

Tags: android

I'm getting an out of memory exception thrown when trying to send an email with an attachment.

Unfortunately unless I increase the size of heap allocation I can't seem to diagnose/fix the problem. The attachment as far as I can tell is not particularly large and it works on some installations but not others.

```
07-18 15:29:58.912 2471-21587/uk.co.nwhub.nwtapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 37440820 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 18MB until OOM"
07-18 15:29:58.922 2471-21587/uk.co.nwhub.nwtapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[EmailService]
Process: uk.co.nwhub.nwtapp, PID: 2471
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 37440820 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:133)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
   at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:119)
   at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:133)
   at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
   at com.amazonaws.util.HttpUtils.urlEncode(HttpUtils.java:74)
   at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.getCanonicalizedQueryString(AbstractAWSSigner.java:173)
   at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS3Signer.sign(AWS3Signer.java:112)
   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:326)
   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
   at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:2630)
   at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendRawEmail(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:1525)
   at uk.co.nwhub.nwtapp.services.EmailService.onHandleIntent(EmailService.java:126)
   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

All the help/guidance I am reading about state what to do in this scenario when you are dealing with images. I am however not using any images within this activity. What can I do to diagnose/try to resolve this?

Comment: Check Android documentation. I'm gonna go out on a limb and say you have a pretty large image (https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). You can (and I'd probably recommend) you use an Image loading library like Glide, Fresco, UIL, PhotoView...

Comment: AWS's code is trying to allocate 37440820 bytes = ~36MB. That is not going to work reliably. Use whatever AWS offers for support, showing them your code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can set break point at `com.amazonaws.util.HttpUtils.urlEncode(HttpUtils.java:74)`,
then run application by "Debug app", and check the very large string

Comment: I can't do that if this is a production app which has been signed with a different key to my Android studio/development key though can I? I can't uninstall the app from the tablet as that would mean losing the app's data.

Comment: Ok. I thinks there is some options. (1) Change package name. Then do "Debug Run" (2) Do "Debug Run" on another device.